# Pink bird and turtle travelling in time?

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, animation

Back in 2005-2007, there was a TV cartoon series being aired on TV. The show main characters were a pink bird and big yellow beak but didn't look like a flamingo. The main character was accompanied with a female turtle. These two were traveling in time to explore the history of humanity or fly around the city to explain climate change and other global issues. The bird was explaining to the turtle. The show was mainly educational and targeted toward children. Does it ring a bell in anyone's memory?

PS, the show voice-overed in Arabic, but I am certain it was originally English.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Albert Says... The Nature Knows Best

and

### Albert Asks... What is Life?

[Is this your bird?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRmFs_rH7QA) (Youtube link)

> The main character Albert is a mythical creature that, according to the outside, like a combination of bird and hamster. Albert, although cheeky, but is characterized by curiosity and kindness, so that he gets along with all animals. His adventures are for explanation of nature and environment . To this end, Albert has the property to increase or to be able to get plants and elements to the smallest detail to the track out. For this purpose, it can not only fly or run, but also dive and swim. In addition to the importance of nature and the environment, see the animated series also potential hazards and environmental problems attention. In particular, the hazards arising from human or machine threat is discussed.

It's a German show by the way, not English.

[Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_says..._The_Nature_Knows_Best)

**However**, there is no mention of a turtle. I suspect that a turtle may have been part of a specific episode you remember, as opposed to a recurring character that's part of the main plot.

---

**edit**

### I found the turtle!

[Here's the turtle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?gl=BE&v=4iz-lPYu5w8) (Youtube link)

I should have read the Wiki page better:

> A spin-off series, called Albert auf Entdeckungstour (**Albert Asks What is Life?**), was released in 2002.

I can't find any more information on this spin-off series, but the Youtube link shows a turtle, so I'm guessing this is the answer to your question.